# "facile à ..." ou "faciles à ..." ?

Tags: adjectifs, orthographe

Devrais-je plutôt écrire:

> Ces exponentielles sont faciles à simplifier

ou:

> Ces exponentielles sont facile à simplifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Facile*** est un adjectif.

En français, les adjectifs s'accordent toujours donc seule la forme ***faciles à*** est correcte.

On peut parfois rencontrer des utilisations adverbales de *facile* (pour *facilement*), et dans ce cas, il n'y a pas d'accord :

> Ces exponentielles, je les ai résolues facile.

Answer (score 0):

« Sont facile à simplifier / sont faciles à simplifier » n'est pas assez courant pour permettre une vérification aisée au moyen des ngram, mais ce n'est pas le cas  pour « sont facile à voir / sont faciles à voir » ; le résultat ne laisse aucun doute, un s est nécessaire.

[image]

Voilà un autre ngram qui montre que cet usage est solide.

[image]